# Bad database name configuration on symfony

Tags: database, symfony, doctrine

I must take back a little website for an association but i have trouble setting up my development environment.

1. I successfully retrieved the code
2. I just have to launch a docker-compose up inside to launch a sql
   server on localhost on port 3306
3. I have back up the data from the production inside this docker.
4. And i have a .env file looking like this:
   `DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:root@127.0.0.1:3306/bbdr?serverVersion=mariadb-10.5.8"`

So when i start the symfony server, (with symfony serve) i already start having doctrine error coming up while it tried to do the migration. But every time a request is tempted, it's tempted on dbname="root" or in the .env file i put bbdr?
Someone know what i could do wrong here?

---EDIT---

Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
  web:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
    - "8001:80"
    volumes:
        - .:/var/www/html
        - ./docker/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

  php-fpm:
    image: php8-custom
    build: ./docker/php

    volumes:
        - .:/var/www/html

###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
  database:
    image: library/mariadb:10.5.8
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
        - "3306:3306"
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'root'
    volumes:
        - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###

###> symfony/mailer ###
  mailer:
    image: mailhog/mailhog
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
        - "1025:1025"
        - "1010:8025"
###< symfony/mailer ###

volumes:
###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
  db-data:
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
```

Comment: could you please, provide us your docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your docker-compose.yml, add the `MYSQL_DATABASE` key and value

```yaml
services:
    database:
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: bbdr
```

Comment: It solved my problem indeed, but i don't understand. I thought the name of the database was defined inside the .env file? Why do i also have to write it here?